# Javascript async/await execution order problem in for...of, for await...of and Promise.all

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, async-await

For each object (product) in an array (products), I'm getting the price from a mongoose database. That value (prodDB.price) is summed to the "amount" variable initialized as 0 before the loop.

I tried 3 solutions explained in other questions, with:

- for of
- for await of
- Promise.all

--- for of ---

```
 let amount = 0;
     
 for (const product of products) {
     await Product.findById(product._id).exec((err, prodDB)=> {
         amount += product.count * prodDB.price;
         console.log("Current amount", amount);
     });
 };
 console.log("Amount total", amount);
```

--- for await of ---

```
 let amount = 0;
     
 for await (const product of products) {
     Product.findById(product._id).exec((err, prodDB)=> {
         amount += product.count * prodDB.price;
         console.log("Current amount", amount);
     });
 };
 console.log("Amount total", amount);
```

--- Promise.all ---

```
let amount = 0;

await Promise.all(products.map(async (product)=> {
    await Product.findById(product._id).exec((err, prodDB)=> {
    amount += product.count * prodDB.price;
    console.log("Current amount", amount);
    });
}));

 console.log("Amount total", amount);
```

The result of any of the previous versions of the code is always the same, and unexpected, particularly the order in which console.log happens:

```
Amount total 0
Current amount 10.29
Current amount 17.15
Current amount 18.29
Current amount 19.45
Current amount 43.2
```

Can you please help?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing "callback" mode and "await" mode. Either `await` the operation, or give it a callback, otherwise it gets messy.

```
for (const product of products) {
    let prodDB = await Product.findById(product._id).lean().exec(); // add lean() to get only JSON data, lighter and faster
    amount += product.count * prodDB.price;
    console.log("Current amount", amount);
};
```

However, this is very expensive, because if you have 10 products, you call your database 10 times. Better call it only once and fetch all _id in one go.

```
let allIds = products.map(p => p._id),
    prodDBs = await Product.find({
        _id: {
            $in: allIds
        }
    })
    .lean()
    .exec()

const amount = prodDBs.reduce((a,b) => a.price + b.price, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Promise.all` so you can run all the DB request in parallel and wait for all them to complete, instead of running all of them in series. The only issue I think is with `.exec()` not returning a `Promise`, just use `findById()` that returns a Promise, try this code:

```js
let amount = 0;

await Promise.all(products.map(async (product)=> {
  const prodDB = await Product.findById(product._id)
  amount += product.count * prodDB.price
}));
```

Comment: Still making 10 database calls instead of one, though :/