# Complete promise before next iteration of for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know for sure this is a duplicate question. However it's been a good minute since i've written javascript and need an update with how to achieve this. I attempted to use async await but the specific package i'm using seems to not allow it (or i'm most likely using async await incorrectly). I'm using the `google-trends-api`. I'm wanting to wait for the `googleTrends.interestOverTime` fetch to resolve before moving to the next iteration of the `j` for loop.

```
const dogs = require('./dog_database');
const googleTrends = require('google-trends-api');
const moment = require('moment');

let threeMonthsAgo = moment()
    .subtract(3, 'months')
    .format();

for (i = 0; i < dogs.breeds.length; i++) {
    let currentDog = dogs.breeds[i];

    (async function dogComparision() {
        for (j = 0; j < dogs.breeds.length; j++) {
            let dogBeingCompared = dogs.breed[j];

            if (dogBeingCompared === currentDog) {
                console.log('Just passed current dog.');
            } else {
                // this is the fetch
                await googleTrends
                    .interestOverTime({keyword: [currentDog, dogBeingCompared], startTime: new Date(threeMonthsAgo)})
                    .then(function(results) {
                        console.log(results.default.averages);
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.error('Error returned', err);
                    });
            }
        }
    })();
}
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript async/await execution order problem in for...of, for await...of and Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64337908/javascript-async-await-execution-order-problem-in-for-of-for-await-of-and-p)

Comment: I'm a little confused with what you sent me, I only have one promise to resolve

Comment: @srb633 — If you only have one promise, then you only have one breed of dog and don't need it in an array to loop over in the first place.

Comment: So you're saying each variable defined for each iteration needs to be a promise in it self? It would be much easier if you just show me.

Answer (score 0):

Use await when calling your async function within the for loop.

If you have a lot of places in your app where you want to use something like this, consider using a library that supports Observables.

Comment: I placed await next to the fetch within an async function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is inside of the async function. The fetch is within the `j` loop. Do you mean I need to place both loops inside the async function?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
await googleTrends
                    .interestOverTime({keyword: [currentDog, dogBeingCompared], startTime: new Date(threeMonthsAgo)})
                    .then(function(results) {
                        console.log(results.default.averages);
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.error('Error returned', err);
                    });
```

With:

```
    let results = googleTrends.interestOverTime({keyword: [currentDog, dogBeingCompared], startTime: new Date(threeMonthsAgo)})
                          .catch(function(err) {
                            console.error('Error returned', err);
                        });
    console.log(results.default.averages);
```

So you await the results, and have it in hand                   before the next iteration.
But notice this wouldn't make the call to dogComparision to be sync.. so the print order still isn't something you can count on